# Use machine learning to analyze sports bets

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Lets say I have database with over 1 Million bets (all kinds of sports) made by couple thousands of users, over a period of 2 years (and still growing).

These data are just lying around doing nothing, so I thought if it would be possible to use something like https://www.tensorflow.org/, do a bit of tinkering and it would analyze all the bets in database and learn from it some patterns, whats good and whats not.

The point being is we dont have resources to employ dozens of people for god knows how long to write some complicated software from the ground up. So I was thinking we could use some module from TensorFlow and go from there.

So then I would feed the network with new open bets that are currently in the system (those would be bets that are on matches that are about to be played) and it would pick for me what I should bet on, for example there is a 90% chance this bet will win, because 10 very successful players made this bet, and they have very high success when betting on this particular sport.

We have lots of experienced users, they make lots of money from betting. So the system could be trained on the data we have and then it would know, for example, if user A bets on this league/team, its very likely he will win.

The question is, where do we go from here? Can anybody point us in the right direction? Or is this just too difficult to do, for 2 people in few months? Can we use some pre-programmed solutions, like TensorFlow?

Comment: Ok. Do you have a question?

Comment: I added the question

Comment: You should probably check out the underlying betting-theory first. On the outer level: it's not about success in the binary sense, but about expectation (success * reward). And i'm pretty sure, the internal mechanism-design of those bettings are build in a way that it does not matter for them which bets are set (ignoring ideas about the future). It's more user vs. user. This also implies, if correct, that NNs are not much help. Maybe some game-theoretic designs, but i don't know.

Comment: One more addition: remember the fact, that on average, the bets you learn from are losing!

Comment: I would be willing to collaborate, do you still have access to that data? )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without having a look of the data, it is impossible to suggest what direction should you take your next steps but anyway your first step should be to explore your data throughly, create model on small subset of data and test your hypothesis.

Overall you can try to:

1. Use Python or R to Load and Clean Data
2. Take a random subset of data(some 10,000 rows) and create a simple model using SVM or Random Forest looks like a classification Win/Lose.
3. Test your results and verify your hypothesis with some data.
4. Explore about your data to see if you can generate better features
5. Design a small neural network first and then think about a deep neural network using tensorflow or keras etc.

Have a look at this: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-create-your-own-machine-learning-predictive-system-in-the-nba-using-python-7189d964a371

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will take some time to think about this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible but can be more difficult than it appears.

Consider Microsoft's Cortana which (while only picking if a game will win outright and not ATS) is only approx. 63% accurate; which is quite good but not exactly 90% as you mention in your question *(1)*.

The size of your database should be great for ANN models. It would be a very interesting project for sure!

To your question "where I go from here..." my answer is to simply explore the data in RStudio or using a cloud service such as Microsoft's Azure ML Studio *(2)* or Amazon's Machine Learning services *(3)*.

Good luck!

Ref. 1: http://www.businessinsider.com/nfl-picks-microsoft-cortana-elo-week-5-2017-10

Ref. 2: https://studio.azureml.net/

Ref. 3: https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-ai/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.